# Room + Live Data Debugging

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to make a login function which will check if the username exists in db:-

I need to get the live data successfully from Room database to Repository to view-model. Below is the code. It isnt working but will try one of the suggestion already.

when i load from DB line :-

```
 UserDetails= dao.loadUserDetails(UserName);
    Log.v("Response", UserDetails.getValue().getToken());
```

I get cannot invoke Null.....

I am confused about whats the best way also to implement such a function and how to fix this.

Repository

```
public MutableLiveData<String> LoginUser(String UserName,String Password ) {
//
//        rUserDetails.setUsername("nadeem");
//        rUserDetails.setPassword("test");
//        rUserDetails.setToken(AppConstants.PARAMS);
//        rUserDetails.setSid("1234");
//        rUserDetails.setResourcId(Long.valueOf(12134));
//        insert(rUserDetails);


     UserDetails= dao.loadUserDetails(UserName);
    Log.v("Response", UserDetails.getValue().getToken());

    if(UserDetails.getValue()!=null) {
        rUserDetails.setUsername(UserName);
        rUserDetails.setPassword(Password);
        rUserDetails.setToken(AppConstants.PARAMS);
        Observable<MainResponse> mainResponseObserver = mtsAPI.GetSessionID("token/login", AppConstants.PARAMS + "");
        mainResponseObserver.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<MainResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(MainResponse mainResponse) {
                        Log.v("Response", mainResponse.getEid());
                        if (mainResponse.getEid()==null) {
                            msessionId.postValue("Token Error");
                        }
                        else {
                            msessionId.postValue("1");
                            rUserDetails.setSid(mainResponse.getEid());

               rUserDetails.setResourcId(mainResponse.getUserVO().getBact());
                            insert(rUserDetails);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
   }
   else {
        msessionId.postValue("E");
    }
    return msessionId;

}
```

I am stuck on the part where i check if the data of the user is in the Room DB. If in room DB it returns UserDetails which is a mutable live data.

I have tested out the DB. It inserts successfully and was reading successfully to when i tested them our separately.

Dao

```
@Dao
public interface UserLoginDetailsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void save(UserLoginDetails user);
    @Query("SELECT sid, Username, Password,ResourcId,Token  FROM 
    UserLogins_tbl 
    WHERE Username = :userId")
    LiveData<UserLoginDetails> loadUserDetails(String userId);
}
```

With Above code i get Cant invoke Null.... on UserDetails.getvalue.getToken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `LiveData` to fetch User Details as declared in this Dao method

```
LiveData<UserLoginDetails> loadUserDetails(String userId);
```

You **cannot** directly call getValue() on `LiveData` and **expect** to get current value. `LiveData` needs an observer to be calculated in first place. In this case value is not fetched synchronously.
You can find same issue [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/44#issuecomment-306966494)

To use `LiveData` you need to observe for changes by passing `LifecycleOwner` like `Activity`, Like they have given in Architecture Component Samples - [ProductFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ui/ProductFragment.java)

```
// Observe product data
model.getObservableProduct().observe(this, new Observer<ProductEntity>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable ProductEntity productEntity) {
        model.setProduct(productEntity);
    }
});
```

If you want the value without observer you can change return type to non `LiveData` like this

```
UserLoginDetails loadUserDetails(String userId);
```

In this case you can't call this method on **main** thread. You need to call this database **synchronous** operation method on background thread like using `Schedulers.io()` thread using `RxJava`.

Possible solution can be to use RxJava with Room to return `Flowable` of the User Data, for example as they shown in Architecture Component Examples - [UserDao.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence/UserDao.java)

Change your loadUserDetails to return `Flowable`

```
Flowable<UserLoginDetails?> loadUserDetails(String userId);
```

Subscribe to that `Flowable` like - [UserViewModel.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/ui/UserViewModel.java)

```
// Map the result to desired format
// Using RxJava operators to perform checks
// If user is null or not
public void checkUserExists(String userId) {
    dao.loadUserDetails(userId)
        .map(new Function<UserLoginDetails, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(UserLoginDetails userLoginDetails) throws Exception {
                if(userLoginDetails == null){
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        })
        .subscribe(getObserver());
}
```

So as you get `Flowable` you can apply various operators to check for your desired **conditions** and may convert this **stream** to **boolean** observable with value dependent on your conditions. This will be much easy and **maintainable** approach for this particular use case.

Comment: Thanks this did help allot. will try to re edit the question though

Comment: I was just curios do you thinks this is the correct approach to implement login for users? or is there better ways .. As i am just a newbie.. Lastly i have a awed problem after i implemented your first part suggested 
    public void onChanged(@Nullable ProductEntity productEntity) {
        model.setProduct(productEntity);
    }
 I seems to now get the data to my Activity, but now the the alert Dialog which shows me the login is success or failed comes about 3 to 4 times every time i click login.